# Jmeter throws Could not create keystore error for HTTPS

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter 2.7 and am trying to hit my test server that is HTTPS.
Per [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106796/setting-up-jmeter-to-do-https) Ant did help me setting https correctly on my machine. It worked fine but then all of a sudden I can't do any https tests. 
I have not made any changes to my settings. I just have protocol set to https. When I run I get the below keystore error. Can some one please tell me how to fix this?

> Could not create keystore: [default =KeyStore.getDefaultType()] not found
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create keystore: [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()] not found
>   at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:116)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.createContext(JsseSSLManager.java:232)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.getContext(JsseSSLManager.java:198)

Comment: What is selected on Implementation field of HTTP Request sampler? Did you test change to Java, HttpCLient 3.1 or HttpClient 4?

Comment: I don't have anything selected for implementation. My test did not change :( I am not even able to hit https://github.com as an example.... I just followed instructions on how to hit a https server.... and am failing.

Comment: Try each implementation to see if any applies. I use JMeter under HTTPS and even with digital certificates and, with HttpClient 3.1, it's working (HttpClient 4 with digital certificates is working only in JMeter 2.7+).

Comment: Still no luck... I tried with all 3 implementation and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me now. I had to uninstall and install jmeter and things seem to be ok now.