# How to capture and use the dynamic value generated in the same service in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a script, where a dynamic value (user_token) is generated. The same value has to be used in the same service. The previous services before this service are using GET methods, so I was not able to use regular expression before the service.

Please find the screen shot of the script.

[image: Image of the services and the dynamic value]

Comment: Can you please elaborate. How is the user_token generated? I guess it is generated from the login request? If yes then is this the variable you want to pass in the following requests?? Also I am a bit confused with the statement can't use regular expression as the service is using GET? You can use regular expression in GET.

Comment: No,The user_token generated in sign.html, which I have to use again in the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please confirm on the below.

If your script is recorded . then the current sampler what you attached, what it tells to us is ,  The user_token is populated automatically while recording . i.e., initially login.html was recorded with username and password you provided , then next sampler signin.html recorded with additional user_token

between login.html and signin.html samplers, you got your user_token ,i.e., login.html response contains user_token ,so  would you please add regex post processor to login.html http sampler and try accessing the  "user_token" value to a variable and use that variable in Signin.html

Comment: User_token is generated from signin.html. and I have to use the same value in the same sampler again...

Comment: I have used the regular expression in login.html as suggested by Suman. Yes it is capturing the value and passing it to the next samplers. Here im receiving an another problem after execution. Im receiving the below error: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name

Please find the screen shot in the above answer i shared.

Comment: if your samplers are expected to use SSL , then you have to add the certificates to your machine. or second choice is disable the use of SSL in the server .  https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/error-handshake-alert-unrecognized_name-when-setting-up-application-links-after-upgrading-confluence-753895174.html   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106796/setting-up-jmeter-to-do-https

Answer (score 0):

I have used the regular expression in login.html as suggested by Suman. Yes it is capturing the value and passing it to the next samplers.
Here im receiving an another problem after execution.
Im receiving the below error:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name**

Please find the screen shot.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ce70.jpg)